# Installing GitHub Desktop on Debian/Ubuntu

Tags: debian, github-desktop

I'm having multiple issues when installing GitHub Desktop through terminal on Debian.

After I installed the `GitHubDesktop-linux-3.0.6-linux1.deb` file from https://github.com/shiftkey/desktop/releases, and I enter this command in the terminal:

`wget -qO - https://packagecloud.io/shiftkey/desktop/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -`

The following message appears:
`OK`

Then, I typed in this command:

`sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packagecloud.io/shiftkey/desktop/any/ any main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/packagecloud-shiftky-desktop.list'`

Nothing happens, and instead it just goes to a new line in the terminal.

I then entered the sudo update command:

`sudo apt-get update`

And finally, I entered the command to install GitHub Desktop:

`sudo apt install github-desktop`

But then the following error appears:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package github-desktop
```

Comment: Should I open the `GitHubDesktop-linux-3.0.6-linux1.deb` file? Or should I leave it?

Answer (score 0):

Try [this guide](https://github.com/git-guides/install-git#install-git-on-linux) from the GitHub website:

> 1. Git packages are available using `apt`.
> 2. It's a good idea to make sure you're running the latest version. To do so, Navigate to your command prompt shell and run the following command to make sure everything is up-to-date: `sudo apt-get update`
> 3. To install Git, run the following command: `sudo apt-get install git-all`
> 4. Once the command output has completed, you can verify the installation by typing: `git version`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).